# Spring Cloud Dataflow/SCDF 2.8.0 in OKD fails

Tags: java, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow, okd

I need to deploy SCDF 2.8.0 version in OKD. I also made changes to SCDF Code to add the Oracle Driver dependency. When I scale up the POD after adding all configurations of SCDF as given in the documentation I get the below error. I tried changing the port but It's of no use.

There are other Rest applications deployed in the same environment and they have no issues in exposing the service via the port 80 or 81. Kindly let me know your inputs.

```
  ____                              ____ _                __
 / ___| _ __  _ __(_)_ __   __ _   / ___| | ___  _   _  __| |
 \___ \| '_ \| '__| | '_ \ / _` | | |   | |/ _ \| | | |/ _` |
  ___) | |_) | |  | | | | | (_| | | |___| | (_) | |_| | (_| |
 |____/| .__/|_|  |_|_| |_|\__, |  \____|_|\___/ \__,_|\__,_|
  ____ |_|    _          __|___/                 __________
 |  _ \  __ _| |_ __ _  |  ___| | _____      __  \ \ \ \ \ \
 | | | |/ _` | __/ _` | | |_  | |/ _ \ \ /\ / /   \ \ \ \ \ \
 | |_| | (_| | || (_| | |  _| | | (_) \ V  V /    / / / / / /
 |____/ \__,_|\__\__,_| |_|   |_|\___/ \_/\_/    /_/_/_/_/_/

Spring Cloud Data Flow Server  (v2.8.0)

2021-06-22 12:24:49.231  INFO 1 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configmap.scdf-server.devfac-capella-batches'}]
2021-06-22 12:24:49.258  INFO 1 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-oracle-root-username'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-oracle-root-url'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-oracle-root-password'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-secrets.spring-cloud-dataflow-server.devfac-capella-batches'}]
2021-06-22 12:24:49.426  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.s.DataFlowServerApplication    : The following profiles are active: dev,kubernetes
2021-06-22 12:24:53.337  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-06-22 12:24:53.338  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Map repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-22 12:24:53.924  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 555 ms. Found 1 Map repository interfaces.
2021-06-22 12:24:55.329  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-06-22 12:24:55.333  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-22 12:24:55.351  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-22 12:24:56.222  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-06-22 12:24:56.222  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-06-22 12:24:56.456  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 233 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-06-22 12:24:57.121  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=46e2ec48-3213-3e84-8b1a-af720b97c983
2021-06-22 12:24:59.309  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 81 (http)
2021-06-22 12:24:59.331  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-81"]
2021-06-22 12:24:59.332  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-06-22 12:24:59.332  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-06-22 12:24:59.608  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-06-22 12:25:01.547  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-06-22 12:25:02.648  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-06-22 12:25:03.020  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-06-22 12:25:03.637  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-06-22 12:25:04.536  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-06-22 12:25:05.046  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
2021-06-22 12:25:06.918  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.validator.internal.util.Version      : HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.7.Final
2021-06-22 12:25:08.958  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-06-22 12:25:09.011  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-22 12:25:09.933  INFO 1 --- [           main] d.c.r.ContainerRegistryAutoConfiguration : Final Registry Configurations: {registry-1.docker.io=ContainerRegistryConfiguration{registryHost='registry-1.docker.io', user='null', secret='****'', authorizationType=dockeroauth2, manifestMediaType='application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json', disableSslVerification='false', useHttpProxy='false', extra={registryAuthUri=https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:{repository}:pull&offline_token=1&client_id=shell}}}
2021-06-22 12:25:12.908  WARN 1 --- [           main] .s.c.d.s.s.i.TaskConfigurationProperties : org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.TaskConfigurationProperties.setComposedTaskRunnerUri is deprecated. Please use org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.ComposedTaskRunnerConfigurationProperties.setUri
2021-06-22 12:25:13.826  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2021-06-22 12:25:14.041  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.b.SimpleJobServiceFactoryBean  : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2021-06-22 12:25:14.730  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-06-22 12:25:15.148  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-06-22 12:25:18.118  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.c.DataFlowControllerAutoConfiguration : Skipper URI [http://localhost:7577/api]
2021-06-22 12:25:18.942  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-81"]
2021-06-22 12:25:18.951  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-06-22 12:25:19.030  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-06-22 12:25:19.041  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-22 12:25:19.045  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-06-22 12:25:19.144  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-06-22 12:25:19.147  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-81"]
2021-06-22 12:25:19.148  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-06-22 12:25:19.154  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-81"]
2021-06-22 12:25:19.155  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-81"]
2021-06-22 12:25:19.746 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.single.DataFlowServerApplication.main(DataFlowServerApplication.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:243)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1074)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:253)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1290)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1071)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

DockerFile I use to build SCDF Image. I build SCDF jar separately with Oracle driver and just use the below docker file to convert into Dockerimage. This is just to reduce the build time.

DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY src/main/resources/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.8.0.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.8.0.jar"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of a research, I found the answer for this question. I get the `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` error. This denotes that the port I'm using which is 80 for SCDF server is not permitted for use in the particular environment. Hence I changed the port to 8081 (Just to have the usual one) and it's started working fine.